# Universal Navigation Bar PHP (Multiple Directories)

Tags: php, html, navigation, directory, include

So I've been using StackOverflow for programming related topics for over 5 years and never once considered registering as 9/10 times I come on, I find what I am looking for. This time, I've trawled the internet, the suggestions from stack overflow, and I can't find the answer, so here I am.

I'm looking to @include a navigation bar to make it universally accessible no matter what page the user is on. The problem is, I have multiple directories, /login
/register
/profile

The list goes on, of course for things such as CSS files, navigation and JS files. I don't want to constantly have to define the href to be '../' or '../../' of a file. That is an insane amount of maintenance for what soon will be a vast directory of PHP files.

The problem I'm having is trying to calculate how I can detect which directory the user is in via the @include file, and if they wish to return home for example, ensuring the correct amount of change directories occur.

I hope I'm making sense here.

I believe I may require the use of $_SERVER but I'm genuinely stuck on even providing code I've attempted to work on. I'm not expecting a hand out, but more an explanation.

Thanks

This is my first attempt, it works to a degree but it's dependent on the page I originally tested the code on. The echo's is simply to see what is going on myself in the background.
This is incredibly easy to perfect using the Laravel framework but doing it normally for some reason I've struggled with it.

```
$host  = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$uri   = rtrim(dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']), '/\\');
$extra = 'index.php';
$folder = $uri;
$folder = "/Folder1/Folder2/Folder3/Folder4/Folder5";
echo substr_count($folder, "/");
echo '<br>' . $folder . '<br>';

$EndLoop = substr_count($folder, "/");

$String = '';

for($Loop = 1; $Loop < $EndLoop; $Loop ++)
{
echo $Loop;

$String = '../' . $String;
echo '<br>';
echo $String;
}
```

**EDIT 2:**

I've just worked this which typically works.. I realized when using a

```
<a href="signup">Sign Up</a>
```

Was routing it to host/directory_currently_in/signup/

So what I have done is this

```
<?php $host = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];

//further down

echo '<a href="http://' . $host . '/signup">Sign Up</a>';
```

Because the signup directory is in the root directory and the individual may be 3 directories further in than the root, I had to try find a way to root them right back up 2 or 3 folders back into the sign up directory.

Using http:// and linking to the host has done this for me. Any suggestions on improvements?

Comment: Make all your URLs absolute instead of relative.

Comment: There's no such thing as `@include` in PHP, it's just `include`.

Comment: please post your working code or what you have tried.

Comment: @Barmar apologies, I'm saying include with an AT symbol from the Laravel framework which is something I'm learning on the side. I meant include.

Comment: @Barmar Thats not actually true. The @ symbol is used for error suppression, so in the event of the file not existing there would be no error.

Comment: @Brogan I know about that, but it's not part of the command name. Anyway, he's now made it clearer that he's talking about a Laravel directive, not the PHP function.

Comment: Thanks for all your feedback, guys. I've added my attempt. It works on some directories but that is dependent on which directory you are actually in.

Answer (score 0):

Try something along the lines of:

```
<?php 
$path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
$path .= "/common/header.php";
include_once($path);
?>
```

That way you are always referring to the base and then building the folder structure from there.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Yoda. I see how this code works. It includes the $path for each folder so how ever many directories you have entered it populates the field, but how exactly will this allow me to go up a directory. Typically using '../' to go up a directory. I mean, surely not every page actually has to include however many ../ it needs?

Comment: Git it a try. FYI:
/  - root of the current drive;
./ - current directory;
../ - parent of the current directory.